# Is there some way to ask Windows Server 2008 R2 to trim the Working Set of its processes less aggressively?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7

We have a server with 16GB of RAM. The memory manager is very aggressive in trimming back the Working Set for a particular process, which is resulting in a lot of soft page faults which is slowing the process down and introducing latency.

Are there any settings we can change in the registry to force the Dynamic Memory Manager to be less aggressive with trimming the Working Set?

We wouldn't mind if the server devoted 80% of its RAM to the Working Set of the processes (its only using 2GB at the moment).

Comment: Note that Microsoft rewrote the memory manager for Windows Server 2008 R2, and built the functionality of Dynamic Cache Service into it. It is now aggressively trimming the working set back too much, which is resulting in hundreds of page faults for our process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up abandoning this line of equiry, as Windows does a pretty good job by default in any case.